# pthread: do other threads stop while the SIGSEGV handler runs?

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, solaris, segmentation-fault

I develop a program on Solaris 10.
I want it to print stack trace on crash. I found this example:

```
static void pstack()
{
  char buf[256];

  sprintf(buf, "/usr/proc/bin/pstack %d |/bin/tee traceback.txt\n", (int)getpid());
  /* undefine LD_PRELOAD to avoid 64-bit problems */
  (void)putenv("LD_PRELOAD=");
  system(buf);
}
void sighanterm(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
    ...
    pstack();
}
```

The interesting thing is: while `/usr/proc/bin/pstack` executes, other threads keep printing their output too.
Do the threads resume when the `system()` is called or they don't stop at all?
Can I stop them explicitly in the handler?

Comment: Well, I have nothing to back this up, but I'd imagine the default handler kills them but when you provide your own handler (as it seems you have) they aren't paused or killed until and unless you do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a handled `SIGSEGV` does not affect any other threads (although if it resulted from memory corruption or other UB, that UB could of course affect other threads). An unhandled `SIGSEGV` on the other hand terminates the whole process.